# Lua Table of Strings to Table of Integers

Tags: lua

I am completely new to lua and I would like some help. I have a Table of numbers in string format. How can I change them to integers? Is there a function that can do this. Or what is the best way.

input = {"1", "2", "3"}

output = {1, 2, 3}

For now I found only function `tonumber` which changes a string to number. So I could solve this with a loop.

Comment: Yes, use a loop and `tonumber`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
local input = {"1", "2", "3"}
local output = {}

for i = 1, #input do
  output[i] = tonumber(input[i])
end
```

or

```
for i,v in ipairs(input) do
  output[i] = tonumber(v)
end
```